# Funding the Polygon Chain Without Gas Fees

Tags: blockchain, ether, gas, polygon

From what I hear, the big value point of the Polygon chain is that it has low gas fees. As far as I can tell, the only way to fund a wallet on the Polygon chain is by converting Ether into Polygon which incurs a huge gas fee. It seem like all they've done is transferred the gas fees from on chain transaction to the funding of the wallet. What am I missing?

Comment: 100% agree with this, you cant use a polygon wallet in opensea, instead you have to convert ETH so it's the same

Comment: As far as I can tell, the main advantage is avoiding gas prices when minting NFTs.

Comment: You can just buy matic direct

Comment: @GGizmos thanks for your comment. Can you elaborate?